# Classes in ArrayList updates each other properties

Tags: java, libgdx

I am creating small firework simulation in LibGDX. I have ArrayList called `particles` and this is filling it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Particle p = new Particle();
    p.position = position;
    p.velocity.x = MathUtils.random(-1f, 1f);
    p.velocity.y = MathUtils.random(-1f, 1f);

    particles.add(p);
}
```

And then in update loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < particles.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + particles.get(i).position.toString() + " + " + particles.get(i).velocity.toString() + " = ");
    particles.get(i).update();
    System.out.println("    " + particles.get(i).position.toString());
 }
```

Particle update function:

```
velocity.add(acceleration);
position.add(velocity);

acceleration.set(0, 0);
```

Velocity is random and every particle have unique velocity but position is the same. Here is output:
`0 (300.0,620.91364) + (-0.94489133,-0.45628428) = 
    (299.0551,620.45734)
1 (299.0551,620.45734) + (0.3956585,0.5208683) = 
    (299.45078,620.9782)
0 (299.45078,620.9782) + (-0.94489133,-0.45628428) = 
    (298.5059,620.5219)
1 (298.5059,620.5219) + (0.3956585,0.5208683) = 
    (298.90155,621.0428)
0 (298.90155,621.0428) + (-0.94489133,-0.45628428) = 
    (297.95667,620.5865)
1 (297.95667,620.5865) + (0.3956585,0.5208683) = 
    (298.35233,621.10736)`
First is particle index, position, velocity and then output position.

Why is it using position from another particle? I am trying to figure it out but I can't.

Comment: You are reusing your `position` object inside your `Particle` class. They reference all the same `position` object. Check where you have `new Position()` in your code (assuming that's the class name), and how often this line is executed in your code.

Comment: This kind of error is very common and is one of the reasons modern coding guidelines recommend making your classes immutable. (For example, all the classes in the java.time package, introduced in Java 8, are immutable.)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The problem with using immutable classes in Java games is that it causes GC churn, which causes little stutters in the frame rate. Java unfortunately doesn't have structs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your for loop where you fill the ArrayList you have the line:

```
p.position = position;
```

I don't know where `position` comes from but here all Particles point to the same.

You must create a new Position for every Particle

```
p.position = new Position(x, y);
```

If `position` is the start point for your Particles you can write:

```
p.position = new Position(position.x, position.y);
```